# Spying rectangles for IE browser website do not match interface elements (Blue Prism)

Tags: internet-explorer, blueprism, rpa

I am using Blue Prism and am trying to spy/identify some elements on a webpage in IE. The website is https://www.vesselfinder.com/.
The Application Modeller is unable to identify many elements on the page, the identification rectangle (prior to Ctr-Left Click) does not show or shows 'off' the element I want to capture. 
Try for example to spy/identify the 'Vessels' top menu header or the 'Search by Ship Name/ IMO/ MMSI.
Can someone share his/her thoughts on why the spying fails?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in my environment I can spy both elements, tough you'll have a tough job with "search by ship name" field!

Please check these two things:

- is there any scaling used in your windows. (search for 'change the size of text, apps, and other items' in windows start)
- is there any zoom used in your internet explorer

Comment: Thank you, I just found out myself as well. I am using a laptop and another computer. For the laptop the 100% view setting suitable for Blue Prism makes other tasks rather uncomfortable (reading, editing images, etc), so I changed it back a while ago, never realizing that I did so when I took up Blue Prism again on the laptop. Really appreciate your input!